# How to get access to a bunch of elements (Gridpane type in my case) stored into an observableList?

Tags: java, javafx

First of all my apologize because my poor english.

I have 5 Gridpane that i need to set disabled/enabled on depending some circumstances. I tried to store it into an ObservableList but when i try to get access to them for apply .setDisable method throws error, because I check what return when i call any index, and its null instead a gridpane. Help me please :(

Here is the code:

```
@FXML
private GridPane fila1;
@FXML
private GridPane fila2;
@FXML
private GridPane fila3;
@FXML
private GridPane fila4;
@FXML
private GridPane fila5;

@FXML
ObservableList<GridPane> mesas = FXCollections.observableArrayList(fila1,fila2,fila3,fila4,fila5);


for(int i=0;i<temp.getEmpleados().size();i++) {
           mesas.get(i).setDisable(false);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ObservableList` is created in the initializer, since you assign the value in the field declaration. However the `GridPane`s are injected later. At the time

```
ObservableList<GridPane> mesas = FXCollections.observableArrayList(fila1,fila2,fila3,fila4,fila5);
```

is executed, the fields still contain the initial values of `null`.

To get a list of the injected `GridPane`, you need to create/assign the `ObservableList` **after** the `GridPane`s have been injected, e.g. in the [`initialize`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/Initializable.html#initialize-java.net.URL-java.util.ResourceBundle-) method:

```
@FXML
ObservableList<GridPane> mesas;

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    mesas = FXCollections.observableArrayList(fila1,fila2,fila3,fila4,fila5);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, just one more question, what is this? 
(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) because i use just "initialize ()"

Comment: Using `initialize()` is fine too, however personally I like having an interface that declares the appropriate method signature (for compile time checking for typos) and theredore use the `Initializable` interface.